# Android Emulator on Mac OS X issues clicking

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Really weird issue but when I try to click once it doesn't register on the emulator but then I click again and the click registers. This is using AVD. Every other click seems to trigger in the proper place. This has nothing to do with my app just base image.

Take a look at this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axvxtGj4HPo&feature=youtu.be

and notice the first click doesn't register.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axvxtGj4HPo&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 18):

I notice the age on this thread, so not sure if you have already figured this out. I ran into something similar like this today in which no clicks were being registered at all. This issue still persisted even after closing and reopening the simulator. One thing I did notice is that the power button still worked.

I ended up fixing this by:

1. Clicking and holding the Power Hard Key
2. Restarting the device OS by clicking the Restart

After the OS Reboots, everything seems to work again.

Note: the Hard Key for power is the power button next to the volume controls on the right.

[image: AVD Screenshot]

Comment: I can't remember exactly what I did but probably a combination of restarting or downloading a new image helped. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: After restart, random clicking have stopped! Thanks!

Comment: After short period of time, it started to happen again... not sure what to do...

Comment: holding the power button fixed the left click not working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it usually happens when the size on disk is very high (see in AVD Manager) and the solution in my case is to make a `Wipe Data`

Update #1 (Because the solution from above not always works)

Another thing I found is that when you want to swipe up from the Google bar does not open the apps menu. Then I open first the Messages app or Chrome and close again. From there the Swipe up works again.

[image]